# How to declare objects while iterating

Tags: c++, struct, iteration

I apologize for asking what seems like a really pedestrian question but i've been researching the topic for days unable to find an answer. Suppose I have a file with lines associated with users information, something like:

```
Roberts John 25
Peters Kelly 22
```

And i want to store each line as an object (of a struct), then store pointers to these objects in a vector, without knowing how many lines to expect. The notation i know for creating an object (lets say the structure is called User, and the vector is called Users) is

```
User Roberts;
Roberts.age = 25;
...
Users.push_back(&Roberts)
```

Instead of saying "create an object called 'roberts' and give it these values' how do i say 'create an object and give it these values'?

I understand that for my example, I have no real reason to use a structure, but my actual purpose is more complicated so i've only provided a simple example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You should use a vector of objects instead of a vector of pointers. All problems will be solved. If you create an object in a loop, it will be lost at next iteration

Comment: The process you are looking for is called "parsing". Basically, you need to extract `User` info from a string and use them to populate an instance. BTW: Adding the address (`&Roberts`) of a local object to a container is going to get you in trouble. Avoid using pointers, unless there's a good reason!

Comment: Are you using at least c++11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use pointers at all.  Just use a vector of objects:

```
struct User
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<User> users;
    std::ifstream ifs("YourFile.txt");
    User user;
    while (ifs >> user.first_name &&
           ifs >> user.last_name &&
           ifs >> user.name) {
        users.push_back(std::move(user));
    }
}
```

If you really, really want to use pointers, you'll need to allocate the object on the free store, so that pointers to it remain valid after it goes out of scope:

```
struct User
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<User>> users;
    std::ifstream ifs("YourFile.txt");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
        std::unique_ptr<User> user = std::make_unique<User>();
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> user->first_name;
        iss >> user->last_name;
        iss >> user->age;
        users.push_back(std::move(user));
    }
}
```

Objects allocated on the free store must be explicitly deleted when you're done with them.  I've used `std::unique_ptr` to handle that deletion.  If you were use raw pointers you would have to make sure to `delete` each object before the vector holding the pointers to them goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<User> Users; // Save the object not the pointer.
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    User user;
    user.age = i;
    Users.push_back(user); // A clone of user will be pushed into the vector.
}
```

Comment: Better to move contents: `Users.push_back(std::move(user));`.

Comment: If you have `std::move` you also have `emplace_back` and can construct the new object inside the vector, eliminating the need for the temporary, moves, and copying.